# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi$NoPadding

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle

Trying to encrypt using .cer. It works in the local system but getting error when I move to production.
I have the bcprov-jdk15on-158.jar file at Live server.

Source code

```
public static byte[] encryptUsingPublicKey(byte[] data, PublicKey publicKey) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");//Here iam Getting Error
    pkCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] encSessionKey = pkCipher.doFinal(data);
    return encSessionKey;
}
```

error stack trace

```
        INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.bouncycastle.jca.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi$NoPadding.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown forbugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functio impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1777)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1636)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:668)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:595)
        at in.gov.cgg.struts.utilities.common.TAEncrypter.encryptUsingPublicKey(TAEncrypter.java:134)
        at in.gov.cgg.struts.utilities.common.TAEncrypter.EncryptRequest(TAEncrypter.java:57)

       ...

java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:687)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:595)
        at in.gov.cgg.struts.utilities.common.TAEncrypter.encryptUsingPublicKey(TAEncrypter.java:134)
        at in.gov.cgg.struts.utilities.common.TAEncrypter.EncryptRequest(TAEncrypter.java:57)
        at in.gov.cgg.struts.actions.RequestHandlerAction.unspecified(RequestHandlerAction.java:78)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:256)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
       ....
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for Cipher (provider: BC) cannot be found.
        at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1649)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:668)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi$NoPadding
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1636)
        ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` generated when the class is not available in your `classpath`. Check you `classpath` included the expected jar. Even it is on server but might not included in the classpth.

There is no other reason for `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
changed `Cipher pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");` working for me